# How do I return a list of all column titles in a table in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a 20-or-so column table 'Contacts' in a Contacts.sqlite file.  I use the Mac Terminal to interact with it, and am writing a program that will perform certain actions based on the number of columns in the table, as well as the name of each column.

Thus, I need to perform some sort of query that will return a list of all my column titles.

I have found various recommendations that look like some version of this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'Schema' AND table_name = 'Table_Name'
```

but it almost always returns an error saying there is "no such table: information_scheme.columns".

Comment: Please don't use tags that don't apply to your question

Comment: Hmm, I didn't believe I used irrelevant tags, but I will do my best. DCoder found a great article: the .schema command worked well. Andomar's solution worked well, also. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like SQLite does not support `information_schema`.  You can retrieve the list of table names from `sqlite_master`.  But there is no table with columns.

Instead, SQLite supports the proprietary  [`pragma table_info()`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html):

```
pragma table_info(table_name);
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't believe I used irrelevant tags, but I will do my best. DCoder found a great article: the .schema command worked well.
Andomar's solution worked well, also.

Thanks so much!